# Unable to load the specified metadata resource in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-config

My connection string look like below:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data     Source=172.16.0.29;Initial Catalog=audiss;Integrated Security=rue; User ID=audiss;Password=india@123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="AudEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AudissDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.AudissDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.AudissDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient; 
     provider connection string=&quot; data source=172.16.0.29;initial catalog=audiss;integrated security=True;
     user id=audiss;password=india@123 MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
     App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

While running with this I got "Unable to load the specified metadata resource" error. I tried so many things but could not resolve this error.

Is there any problem in Integrated security section in my connection string? or any other error causing this exception?

Please try to get out of this.

Comment: What things did you try?  What were the results?

Comment: Why are you putting the user and password if you're using integrated security?